# Cronjob in ASP .NET Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cron

i've problems with CronJobs. I tried a lot of codes but nothing works. I really don't understand the reason. here is my code

```
public class CronJobServices : BackgroundService
{
    private CrontabSchedule _schedule;
    private DateTime _nextRun;

    private string Schedule => "0/20 * * ? * * *"; //Runs every 20 seconds

    public CronJobServices()
    {
        _schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse(Schedule, new CrontabSchedule.ParseOptions { IncludingSeconds = true });
        _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
    }


    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        do
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var nextrun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(now);
            if (now > _nextRun)
            {
                Process();
                _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
            }
            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken); //5 seconds delay
        }
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    }

    private void Process()
    {
        InfoServer.SendMail("mymail@gmail.com", "Hello", "CronJobServices");
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddSingleton<CronJobServices>();
    }
```

InfoServer.SendMail is a method that simply send mail and it works fine, I'm using a lot for other reason.

I even tried to use IHostedService but nothing works.
Any idea?

EDIT: CrontabSchedule cames from NCrontab NUGet